# Find and remove in unix

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk

Below is my input file:

`sample.txt`:

```
3"
6-position
7' 4" to 10' 3-1/2"
4.8"
Adjustable from 99" to 111" - max 148
```

and in the output I only need 3, i.e.

`output.txt`:

```
3
4.8
```

So basically I need to print the numeric value for the `"` symbol, other non-numeric text needs to be removed entirely.

I tried to implement this with `sed`, but I was not able to get the desired result.

Is there any way to achieve this on UNIX?

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what you're trying to do. Are you attempting to find the first number followed by a quotation mark (or inch mark, I guess) and then create an output file with just the number in it?

Comment: Hi @Greg, i need only the numeric value with inch mark(like 3" and 7.8")
and i want to delete the remaining values like '8-height',7'4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk is more suited to perform this type of task:

```
awk '/^ *[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" *$/{sub(/"/, ""); print}' inFile
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
3
4.8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @anubh it worked, can you please explain this command
`{sub(/"/, "")` is similar to sed command? replacing " with emptry line?? please explain?

Comment: My first regex `/^ *[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" *$/` is making sure online line s with decimal number followed by ' are matched. And then `sub(/"/, "");` is replacing `"` with empty string to leave only numbers in output.

Comment: Thanks Again @anubh, is it possible to modify this awk command to work in delemted file. i.e. to manupicate this command on certain column?
i tried the below command for manipulating this on 2nd column `awk -F ','  '$2= /^ *[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" *$/{sub(/"/, ""); print $2}'`, but this is not working. i dont have not big knowledge in unix, sorry if that command is stupid..

Comment: Yes you can do: `awk -F ',' '$2 ~ /^ *[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" *$/{sub(/"/, "", $2); print $2}'`

Comment: thanks again, is it possible to change command in into sed? beacuse in my feed i have lot of columns so replacing is the best option.

Comment: last question @anubhav, is it possible to print the ouput like below
`3`
`newline`
`newline`
`4.8`
`newline`

Comment: So you want 2 newlines after 3 and only one after 4.8 ?

Comment: ya correct @anubahav, i'm trying if else in awk to achive this but no luck.

Comment: You can post your script as a separate question and leave link in the comments here.

Answer (score 1):

One way with sed:

```
sed -n 's/^\([0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)\?\)"$/\1/p' sample.txt > out.txt
```

or with `GNU sed`

```
sed -rn 's/^([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)"$/\1/p' sample.txt > out.txt
```

or with `GNU grep`

```
grep -oP '^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(?="$)' > out.txt
```

Be sure to use the correct inch mark (`”` or `"`). Or you can match both with a character class `[”"]`.

**Edit:** updated to work for floating point numbers.

Comment: Hi @lev, i tried this command but this command generating only the empty file, got getting the expected result.

Comment: @GanzRicanz I tested all of them on your sample, the output is `3`. Please make sure you don't mix `”` and `"`. Edit: Ah, it's `"` after your edit. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks for replying @lev, Still no luck. i tried `sed -n 's/^\([0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)\?\)"$/\1/p' sample.txt > out.txt` i'm only getting the empty file.

Comment: @GanzRicanz Your `sample.txt` must be somehow different from what you posted then. Can you try copying from the question to a file and using that file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for `grep -o [0-9][0-9]*\" sample.txt` Which will match one or more numbers followed my a '"', and print each occurrence separately and without surrounding text.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^[0-9.]\+"/!d;s/".*//' file
```

Comment: @GanzRicanz this solution will delete any line in the `file` that doesn't start with one or more integers or a points followed by a `"`. If it finds such a line it then removes the `"` and anything following to the end of the line and then prints the remainder. HTH.